# How to clear Bootstrap table data before updating view - laravel livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

There are two dropdowns and one is dependent on other. All things are working well but after changing the value of first dropdown, i want to clear the bootstrap table data and then after changing the value of dependent dropdown, load new data.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. If you need help implementing that, you'll need to show us what you've done so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.